# I got red underline on "#include <iostream>" using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I don't know why I got red underline on `#include <iostream>`. I use VSCode for IDE and C/C++ has installed. My code is very basic but I don't know why it still have red underline.

My code :

```
#include <iostream>    //This line got red underline.
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello";
    retern 0;
}
```

While it run.

> [Running] cd "c:\Users\hola\Desktop" && g++ testplusplus.cpp -o testplusplus && "c:\Users\hola\Desktop"testplusplus
> 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
>
> [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.05 seconds

Comment: You have two unrelated errors. The second error is caused by `g++` not being in the PATH. The first one is a false positive, it's solely a VSC problem and wouldn't stop you from running the program. I think if you hover the error, it explains how it can be fixed.

Comment: Have you installed `g++`?

Comment: Did you tell VSC that this is a C++ program?

Comment: @Mayur I did't even know what is g++. I think I didn't installed g++.

Comment: `g++` is c++ compiler. You need to install one of compiler to compile your c++ programs

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I tell VSC already.

Comment: you can do a bit google to know how to install C++ compiler in windows/linux and how to configure C++ settings in vscode

Comment: I can fix it now. Thanks guys.

Comment: The compiler that provides the `g++` command is called MinGW, or GCC. There are many distributions of varying quality, [here's a decent installation guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2).

Comment: Have you followed the [installation instructions?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This is because the g++ compiler is not installed (and/or not added to the PATH environment variable, [this will probably help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612744/how-to-add-g-from-mingw-to-path/48828104)). [MinGW](https://www.mingw-w64.org/) is the GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) adaptation for Windows, and thus should be used.

Concerning the preprocessor directive `#include <iostream>` there are some rare occasions where IDEs and underlying compile-time processes return a false-positive (It could happen on any line in the file).